# Objective-C Does not Print (NSLog and PrintF Not WORKING!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, printf, nslog

I have searched for hours, tried more than 20 files, and everytime, running in Xcode or through terminal. None will present any output. I restarted terminal and restarted computer. Still no luck. At this point, I have absolutely no clue what's going on.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  NSLog(@"Testing\n");
  printf("Hello\n");
}
```

**In Terminal**

```
gcc -framework Foundation hello.m -o
```

or

```
clang -framework Foundation hello.m -o
```

NEITHER WORK!

I could type the other 50 ones I tried, but let's start very very simple. After running it, there is no output to console. Confused as hell. Everywhere shows output, I tried to switch computers and run it, same thing. What the hell do you set or do to turn on log out put for Objective-C. No tutorials or anywhere covers this.

[image]

Nada printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only compile the file and do not save the result. `-o` option is for write output and because you do not provide a filename, then the compiler just ignores the result and do not save it.
To run it use the following commands:

```sh
clang -framework Foundation hello.m -o test
./test
```

or, as a shortcut,

```sh
clang -framework Foundation hello.m -o test && ./test
```

As you can see, now we specify the name for the output file as `test` and then execute it. Now you will be able to see the output.

Also, be aware that `NSLog` no longer prints to the `stdout` and redirects all messages to the `OSLog` subsystem. You can check such logs in the Console.app. Check the [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) WWDC session if you want to know more.

Comment: I figured a beginner mistake, but this is not covered in almost every beginner walkthrough I saw. Thanks.

Comment: @Ezos, you are welcome. No worries, we all were beginners at some point. Good luck!